# Placing bottom border under <li>

Tags: css, border, html-lists

I need to place a bottom border under outside positioned bullet. I can't use inside positioning because the text wraps under the bullet.
Please let me know if its possible to do what i ask.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you draw a picture in paint of what you're after and post it here?

Comment: can you show your code? That helps the community to help you

Comment: Here is an example of what i need www.toliy.com/li_example.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that I have much better luck using a small image for the bullet. You can control exactly where it goes to the pixel.

```
ul li
{
    background-image: url(images/bullet.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 .5em;
}
```

Comment: can u give me an example of how to use an image for a bullet

Answer (score 0):

*Do you need a border under each li or under the last li in the list?*

Edit: Sorry i'm new to stackoverflow and didn't realize i asked a question in an answer box.

Solution:

Hopefully you are familiar with the fundamentals of a style sheets. If not go [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html):

```
 .listName li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the bullet and use a background image for your bullet. ensure you hide the original bullet and apply padding. example below will work just need to play with the background position.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        li{
            border-bottom:solid #c9c9c9 1px;
            background:url(/bullet.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
            list-style:none;
            margin:0;
            padding-left:20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>example</li>
        <li>example</li>
        <li>example</li>
        <li>example</li>
        <li>example</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```